# Yelp mouse tracking mechanism

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, yelp

I realized Yelp.com does some kind of tracking when the mouse move or something happens (click in element). How does it to this? Is there a library? How to do this without nearly zero performance impact?

You can see Console in Firebug below:

[image]

Comment: Why should have impact? it's not an interval running at 6ms but a hover / click events bound to some targeted objects-elements.

Comment: @roXon But it seems like there's something running every second in addition. (just wanted to point it out)

Comment: Yeah I'm curious why you think it should have an impact. I'm guessing it just binds a bunch of events to specific elements. Specifically the `onmouseover` and `onclick` events. But it also has an interval running every second that probably records where the mouse is. I'm also interested in what library/code this is, and what it's used for.

Comment: I suspect it's part of a fair advertisement procedure, might be to track and prove that there was some actual user input before some targeted action was performed. You might want to do the same if you had some site with ratings and other - where you need to prove there was no automated hitting.

Comment: @roXon you could be right. I am wondering what library that is and whether it's open source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic implementation of the mouse tracking could look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pksah/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
currentPosition = null;
$("#container").on("mousemove", function (event) {
    currentPosition = event;
});


setInterval(function () {
    console.log(currentPosition.pageX + "," + currentPosition.pageY);
}, 1000)
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: why the setInterval? to store mouse movements you could create an array, and only if the mouse moves `.push()` coordinates into your array like i did in this example: http://roxon.in/scripts/MOUSE_RECORDER_roXon_2012/BU_MOUSE_RECORDER.html

Comment: I guess one would not like to log every single event. With the setInterval it logs a sample every second.

Comment: I suppose the log you see on that page has nothing to do with the actual tracking, cause the log is for the user, not for the investigators :) they're getting the desired info in a different way. And the log is not showing mouse coordinates any way AFAICS

Comment: Of course `console.log()` is to be replaced with what you want. For example store it in an Array and do what you wish to do with it afterwards :)

Comment: only tested it in chrome, where it reports the current mouse coordinates

Comment: in that case a delay of 1s could be brely approximative on a rate of 10000 users per hour. A timeout and the `mousemove` event is quite enough! :)

Comment: what are you talking about? 10000 users per hour? with a timeout you get ONE coordinate, the question is about mouse tracking.

Comment: yes, if you're interested on sending some mouse coordinates to your server at a ratio of 1000ms you cannot get any good usable samples , if you get what I mean...

Comment: this is a basic example. surely you would not report to your server every second. you could just collect a couple of samples and then report the whole batch.

Comment: That's exactly what I was talking about! :) I would show that in code too

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comments looks like some advertisements/campaign tracking and it's related to some Google API tools you'll see similarities thrown in the console with this script:

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/!svn/bc/4/trunk/closure/goog/docs/closure_goog_debug_errorhandler.js.source.html

Something with Google ad-sense, closure